# How can I functionally iterate over a collection combining elements?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

I have a sequence of values of type A that I want to transform to a sequence of type B.

Some of the elements with type A can be converted to a B, however some other elements need to be combined with the immediately previous element to produce a B.

I see it as a small state machine with two states, the first one handling the transformation from A to B when just the current A is needed, or saving A if the next row is needed and going to the second state; the second state combining the saved A with the new A to produce a B and then go back to state 1.

I'm trying to use scalaz's `Iteratee`s but I fear I'm overcomplicating it, and I'm forced to return a dummy B when the input has reached EOF.

What's the most elegant solution to do it?

Comment: How do you tell which need the previous element? And what do you do if the first element needs a previous one> However, `coll.sliding(2).map{case(pre, cur)=>if(needsPrevious(cur) combine(pre, cur) else convert(cur)}` would seem straightforward enough

Comment: I have been a little imprecise since I wrote the question thinking at the current implementation; actually more than needing the previous element, I need the next one. That is, at each iteration, I can either convert or I know that I also need the next element to make a conversion.

Comment: Same idea with `sliding(2)` still works. That gives you the current and the next, or the previous and current. They're the same thing, really (two adjacent elements, you just need to pick which is the current one). `coll.sliding(2).map{case(cur, nxt)=>if(needsNext(cur) combine(cur,nxt) else convert(cur)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about invoking the `sliding()` method on your sequence?

You might have to put a dummy element at the head of the sequence so that the first element (the *real* head) is evaluated/converted correctly.

If you `map()` over the result from `sliding(2)` then map will "see" every element with its predecessor.

```
val input:  Seq[A] = ??? // real data here (no dummy values)
val output: Seq[B] = (dummy +: input).sliding(2).flatMap(a2b).toSeq
def a2b( arg: Seq[A] ): Seq[B] = {
    // arg holds 2 elements
    // return a Seq() of zero or more elements
}
```

Comment: I'll try this way; what I really wanted to avoid was adding dummy elements.

Comment: If your first (or last, with the question revised as in your comment) needs the "other" element to combine with,a dummy element is the easiest solution. Why avoid it?

Comment: I've added code to illustrate the concept.  Not every invocation of `a2b()` needs to produce a meaningful data element.

Comment: Indeed, this is exactly what I was looking for. It did not occur to me to make my conversion function return a collection and flatMap() on that.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a stab at it:

Partition your list into two lists. The first is the one you can directly convert and the second is the one that you need to merge.

```
scala> val l = List("String", 1, 4, "Hello")
l: List[Any] = List(String, 1, 4, Hello)

scala> val (string, int) = l partition { case s:String => true case _ => false}
string: List[Any] = List(String, Hello)
int: List[Any] = List(1, 4)
```

Replace the logic in the partition block with whatever you need.

After you have the two lists, you can do whatever you need to with your second using something like this

```
scala> string ::: int.collect{case i:Integer => i}.sliding(2).collect{ 
     | case List(a, b) => a+b.toString}.toList
res4: List[Any] = List(String, Hello, 14)
```

You would replace the addition with whatever your aggregate function is.

Hopefully this is helpful.